# Facebook photo width, height 0

Tags: facebook

Sometime the Facebook JSON data for photos is odd.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

1. Sometimes the width or height is not defined, even though it should be
2. Sometimes the width or height is 0, when then the photo is clearly not

Anyone know what this might happen?

Comment: what extension are they? jpg, png, gif?

Comment: They are .jpg (I believe all Facebook photos are .jpg)